# "-" at the end of post makes previous line render in bold font

Tags: support, markdown

**Update**: turns out it wasn't a bug (see the end of the post and the answer)

#### Original bug report:

Why does [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14683153) comes out looking like this:

[image: The code on the image is blod]

Notice that the code on the image is bold despite the fact that it's outside of the `**` section.

Looking at the page's elements (using Developer tools) shows that the code ended up inside an `<h2>` tag and I can't understand why.

I tried to reproduce this [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/288686/308440), but no luck so far.

**Edit:**

I tried copying the exact markdown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288688/308440). Still can't reproduce anywhere except on the original page.

**Edit:**

Managed to reproduce bug here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288690/308440

**Edit:**

Managed to reproduce with this markdown:

```
`foo`bar
-
```

### `foo`bar

Edit: turns out this wasn't a bug after all. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers. Sorry. Ready to get closed/deleted.

Comment: Edited because I was getting up votes I didn't deserve. Apparently saying "I discovered it's not a bug" at the end of the post wasn't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). The [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#headers) mentions that if you underline using dashes, the previous line is formatted as a header.

### And that is exactly what happens here.

### Apparently, it doesn't matter if you use one dash or multiple ones.

Comment: You can [edit] my post to see the markdown.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered this too (see my last edit).